# datatables formatar campo

Tags: jquery-datatables

Boas, precisava de uma dica: como é que meto o *render* do *datatables* para me mostrar apenas a data da linha abaixo, e para formatar o valor seguinte para o €?

```
   "mrender": function ( data, type, row ) {
                                        //The date value was 2011/04/25, now it's reversed.
                                        //Wed Sep 10 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0700 (SE Asia Standard Time)
                                        var fullDate = row[4].toString();
                                        date = fullDate.substring(8, 10);
                                        month = fullDate.substring(4, 7);
                                        year =fullDate.substring(11, 15);
                                        fixDate = date.concat(" "+month+" "+year);
                                        return fixDate;
                                    },
                                    "targets": 6,
                }
```

2016-04-29 00:00:00.000

45.4400

Comment: Você já tem algum exemplo de código começado para colocar na sua pergunta?

Answer (score 1):

Para datas, eu usaria o [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/):

```
var fullDate = moment(row[4].toString()).format('YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss');
```

Para dinheiro, o [Numeral.js](http://numeraljs.com/):

```
var grana = numeral(45,4400).format('0.0')
```

Comment: isso da para datatables?

Comment: É JS, então serve pra qualquer coisa em JS, inclusive o datatables.